# How to map count query to pojo class?

Tags: hibernate, pojo

I'm trying to execute the query which returns a count of the employees and the department id. How can I assign to pojo. And how to retrieve the resultset from query using hibernate? See my code below:

```
select e.depid, count(empid) from empwithdep e,
   dept d  where e.depid=d.depid group by e.depid order by e.depid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a query returns projections rather than entities, the returned list is a `List<Object[]>`. Each `Object[]` contains the columns returned by the query:

```
List<Object[]> rows = query.list();
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    Long depId = (Long) row[0];
    Long count = (Long) row[1];
    // create a POJO using depId and count...
}
```

This is described in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing-scalar).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an appropriate constructor for your POJO and then use constructor syntax:

```
select new DepartmentInfo(e.depid, count(empid)) from empwithdep e,
    dept d  where e.depid=d.depid group by e.depid order by e.depid
```